# Unload hive table into. dat file using Spark or pyspark or python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am currently unloading data from hive table into text file using hql. Since it is taking too much of time. I would like to go for spark or pyspark.I am new to spark/python.Could you please help on this
currently i am using below query to unload

`beeline --outputformat=dsv --silent=true - e 'select * from <tablename>' > /dir/samplefile.txt`

Let me know for any other performance tunning as well.

Comment: Just to get some clarity, you want the file format to be **.dat** or **.dsv**. As both are two different formats where dat is of generic type and dsv is majorly used by MS SQL. Also you can give a try to use the Sqoop tool

Comment: I want file like. dat and not dsv.  Since i need output file as pipe delimeted file, i gave like outputformat=dsv

Comment: You can read the hive table using the `SELECT` statement which gets stored into a dataframe. Then use the `dataframe.write` method of Spark by specifying the delimiter to get the file in the required location. something like this 
`df.write.option("sep","|").option("header","true").csv(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write spark dataframe directly .DAT files, but we can write in multiple other formats.

For sake of understanding, I will create a dataframe & save it as a hive table.

```
scala> val dbms = Seq((1,2,3, "asd"), (2,3,4,"wee"), (3,4,5, "wer")).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")
dbms: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> dbms.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|asd|
|  2|  3|  4|wee|
|  3|  4|  5|wer|
+---+---+---+---+

scala> dbms.createOrReplaceTempView("dbms")
```

You can follow from here, now your hive table name is dbms, to write the data from hive table using spark follow below steps

```
scala> val data = spark.sql("select * from dbms")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 2 more fields]
```

To write it in text/csv format

```
scala> data.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("output.csv")
```

To write it in widely used parquet format

```
scala> data.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/path/to/hdfs/" + "data.parquet")
```